# Datastructure algorithm needs an explanation

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

How to connect a list of tuples so the input and output looks like:

```
Input:  (5,4),(6,2),(9,3),(2,5),(4,9)
Output: (6,2),(2,5),(5,4),(4,9),(9,3)
```

Each second item of a tuple corresponds the first item of the next tuple.

Comment: Really I cant understand what you want. You want to know what algorithm is used that convert this input to that output?!

Comment: Please explain in more detail how the input is related to the desired output.

Comment: Do you want to shuffle the list in a way that the tuples are connected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want the input indexes replaced in a way that the tuples are connected.

Here is a working example, can be improved in many ways, but I am posting so you'll understand the general algorithm:

Find first tuple - tuple's left elment where there is no other tuple with an equal right element.

Find next tuple - tuple which it's left element equal to the last inserted tuple right elemet, repeat this step as much as needed.

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> input = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    new Tuple<int, int>(5,4),
    new Tuple<int, int>(6,2),
    new Tuple<int, int>(9,3),
    new Tuple<int, int>(2,5),
    new Tuple<int, int>(4,9)
};

List<Tuple<int, int>> output = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

void Main()
{   
    var firstTuple = input.First(item => !(input.Exists(item1 => item1.Item2 == item.Item1)));  
    output.Add(firstTuple);
    AddNextTuple(output[0]);
    AddNextTuple(output[1]);
    AddNextTuple(output[2]);
    AddNextTuple(output[3]);
    // Output: (6,2),(2,5),(5,4),(4,9),(9,3)
}

void AddNextTuple(Tuple<int, int> current){
    output.Add(input.First(item1 => input.Exists(item => item1.Item1 == current.Item2)));   
}
```

Comment: I have edited your questions, added an explanation for the expected output.